# Pyspark 2.0 - IndextoString Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am working on Spark 2.0 using Pyspark for a classification problem. I am trying to get the original names of the predictions of a Classification algorithm. But I am failing to do so.

Code:

```
predictions = dtModel.transform(self._pred)
converter = IndexToString(inputCol="prediction", outputCol="role")
converted = converter.transform(predictions)
```

Error:

```
  File "/hba03/yarn/nm/usercache/sbeathanabhotla/appcache/application_1498495374459_2397452/container_1498495374459_2397452_01_000001/build.zip/src/com/ci/buyerroletagging/service/ModelBuilder.py", line 45, in decision_tree_classifier
    converted = converter.transform(predictions.select('prediction'))
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.0.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.113931/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 105, in transform
    return self._transform(dataset)
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.0.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.113931/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 252, in _transform
    return DataFrame(self._java_obj.transform(dataset._jdf), dataset.sql_ctx)
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.0.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.113931/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.0.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.113931/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/vol1/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.0.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.113931/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o545.transform.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.UnresolvedAttribute$ cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.NominalAttribute
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IndexToString.transform(StringIndexer.scala:313)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Predictions:**

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|           user_guid|            features|       rawPrediction|         probability|prediction|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|9c0393cd-67e1-425...|(239,[1,89,125,21...|[0.0,44.0,0.0,0.0...|[0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|       1.0|
|fdbaccb8-5946-472...|(239,[0,78,124,18...|[96.0,0.0,0.0,0.0...|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|       0.0|
|fdbaccb8-5946-472...|(239,[0,78,130,18...|[96.0,0.0,0.0,0.0...|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|       0.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,123,13...|[0.0,44.0,0.0,0.0...|[0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|       1.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,123,13...|[0.0,0.0,42.0,0.0...|[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,...|       2.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,124,13...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,21.0...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.28...|       3.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,123,13...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,21.0...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.28...|       3.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,128,13...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,21.0...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.28...|       3.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,123,13...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,21.0...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.28...|       3.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,128,13...|[0.0,0.0,42.0,0.0...|[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,...|       2.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,124,13...|[0.0,44.0,0.0,0.0...|[0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|       1.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,124,13...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,21.0...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.28...|       3.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,128,13...|[0.0,44.0,0.0,0.0...|[0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|       1.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,124,13...|[0.0,0.0,42.0,0.0...|[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,...|       2.0|
|883bca4e-9a74-4dd...|(239,[1,28,128,13...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,21.0...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.28...|       3.0|
|58b6246a-7f2a-40b...|(239,[0,64,124,19...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,21.0...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.28...|       3.0|
|58b6246a-7f2a-40b...|(239,[0,64,124,19...|[96.0,0.0,0.0,0.0...|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|       0.0|
|d05b08ab-eef0-496...|(239,[10,80,124,1...|[96.0,0.0,0.0,0.0...|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|       0.0|
|d05b08ab-eef0-496...|(239,[10,80,124,1...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,21.0...|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.28...|       3.0|
|b35a734a-98ba-4e3...|(239,[0,30,129,22...|[96.0,0.0,0.0,0.0...|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|       0.0|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is completely mysterious why, but you need to provide the `labels` argument (although the examples in the documentation seem to work without it). Here is a toy example with my own `predictions` and 2 classes:

```python
predictions.show()
# +-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+ 
# |label|   features|rawPrediction|probability|prediction|
# +-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+ 
# |    0|[140.0,0.0]|    [2.0,0.0]|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|
# |    0|[150.0,0.0]|    [2.0,0.0]|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|
# |    1|[160.0,1.0]|    [0.0,2.0]|  [0.0,1.0]|       1.0|
# |    1|[170.0,1.0]|    [0.0,2.0]|  [0.0,1.0]|       1.0|
# +-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+

converter = IndexToString(inputCol="prediction", outputCol="role", labels=['a', 'b'])
converted = converter.transform(predictions)
converted.show()
# +-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+----+ 
# |label|   features|rawPrediction|probability|prediction|role|
# +-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+----+ 
# |    0|[140.0,0.0]|    [2.0,0.0]|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|   a|
# |    0|[150.0,0.0]|    [2.0,0.0]|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|   a|
# |    1|[160.0,1.0]|    [0.0,2.0]|  [0.0,1.0]|       1.0|   b|
# |    1|[170.0,1.0]|    [0.0,2.0]|  [0.0,1.0]|       1.0|   b|
# +-----+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+----+
```

If I omit the `labels` argument, I get the same error as you. So, if your own labels go from 0.0 to 3.0 as in your sample, you will need something like `labels=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` - in general, `labels` must be a list of the same length as the number of your labels.

Comment: Order of the list of labels place any role here.

Comment: Not sure - I suggest to experiment

Comment: To add to @desertnaut's answer, the reason you need to provide the labels is because the prediction column that is generated by the model doesn't have the metadata necessary to convert the values back to the strings. That metadata is stored in column that you performed the StringIndexer on.

Comment: While this answer explains more clearly, it avoids the main question: how to know what order the labels should be in.  I *feel* like @waterg 's answer addresses it, even though it does not explicitly do so.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting metadata and labels from dataframe and apply the labels below

```
# Make predictions.
predictionsRaw = model.transform(testData)

# Convert predictions back to labels
meta = [
    f.metadata for f in predictionsRaw.schema.fields if f.name == "labelIndex"]
labels = meta[0]["ml_attr"]["vals"]

from pyspark.ml.feature import IndexToString
converter = IndexToString(inputCol="prediction", outputCol="predictedLabel",   labels=labels)
PredictedLabels = converter.transform(predictionsRaw)

# Select example rows to display.
PredictedLabels.select("label","labelIndex","prediction", "predictedLabel", "features").show(5)
```

Comment: It is a good practice to explain what your code is doing, even if the code answer the question.